# Eclipse autocomplete in switch-case

Tags: java, eclipse, autocomplete

Code:

```
private final int A0 = 0;
private final int A1 = 1;

.....

int a = 0;
....
switch (a) {
case [Ctrl + Space]
}
```

When I press Ctrl + Space, I hope eclipse shows a list included A0 and A1, but it doesn't. How to fix this issue?

I'm using Indigo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make them real constants:

```
private static final int A0 = 0;
private static final int A1 = 1;
```

or type `A0` yourself.

Comment: Yes I know, but why need static?

Comment: You don't need it (unless the method containing the switch is itself static). The code compiles with non-static final fields. But if you want to define global constants, static is needed. Each instance of your object will have its own copy of a non-static final field. If the field is static, it's tied to the class, and not to each instance.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use enums instead of Java 1.4 type constants.  Then Eclipse knows the type and can provide you only the enum values.  It also is smart enough to show you the values that have yet to be supplied in the case:

```
private enum A {
  e0,
  e1,
  // end
  ;
}

A a = A.e0;

switch (a) {
    case e0:
    case [Ctrl + Space] // this will expand to e1
}
```